# Need to integrate single user login in both Kohana 3.3 and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a Kohana 3.3 website. I have to integrate a WordPress blog. But once the user logged in the website, he needs to login to the WordPress blog also...

I need suggestion from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the user email by url and get it in the wordpress page,

```
function auto_login($email) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        //determine WordPress user account to impersonate
        $user_login = $email;

       //get user's ID
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
        $user_id = $user->ID;

        //login
        wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
    }
}
```